# How to use Secrets Manager for storing Github token when configuring CodeBuild using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to configure CodeBuild using CloudFormation while storing the Github token using Secrets Manager. It's not working.  Is it even possible to use Secrets Manager for storing Github token?

I followed the documentation, and all I get is CodeBuild error 400 when creating the stack:

> Failed to call CreateWebhook, reason: Could not find access token for server type github (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: ***-***-***; Proxy: null)